# Solr 4.10 returning SolrDocument instances with empty map when dynamic fields are requested

Tags: solr, solrj

I recently upgraded from Solr 4.9 to 4.10.
At some point in the code I want to return the values for some dynamic fields.
If I do this:

```
    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
    query.addField("code");
    query.addField("name");
```

it returns the right values in the fields ('code' and 'name').

If I do this:

```
    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
    query.addField("code");
    query.addField("name");
    query.addField("*_prop");
```

all the fields ,including code and name, are null.

Is there any trick that I missed when moving to 4.10?

Comment: Was this working in 4.9? If so, there might be a regression and worth a bug report.

Comment: Yes. I rolled back to 4.9 and it's working again.

Comment: I reported a bug in apache JIRA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bug in solr 4.10.0.
It was fixed as per https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-6501